# How to mount automatically sshfs when RSA authentication is not an option?

Tags: ssh, mount, fstab, sshfs

I would like to mount a file system on a remote machine automatically at each Linux startup. However I always need to use password authentication because I cannot `use ssh-copy-id`. How do I make this to be automatic without manual interaction?

Comment: Does "can't use `ssh-copy-id`" mean you can't change *anything* on the server? Or just you can't use a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file? (There are more than two authentication options.)

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
echo $mypassword | sshfs -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host mountpoint -o workaround=rename -o password_stdin
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `sshpass` command to login via password authentication, but non-interactively:

```
echo "MyPassword" > passwordfile
chmod 600 passwordfile
sshpass -f passwordfile [ssh parameters]
```

Using this technique is not recommended, as it causes a number of security issues. From `sshpass` man page:

> It is close to impossible to securely store the password, and users of sshpass should consider whether ssh's public key authentication provides the same end-user experience, while involving less hassle and being more secure.

You can then use the `ssh_command` option of sshfs to use sshpass instead of plain ssh

```
sshfs user@host mountpoint -o ssh_command='sshpass -f passwordfile ssh'
```

Comment: sorry this comment is late, but i would recommend making the passwordfile readable only as root (as root: `chown passwordfile ; chmod 400 passwordfile`), and putting the filesystem mount command in your `/etc/fstab`. it's not perfect security (or even "good" security), but it's better than having an exposed plaintext password.

Comment: Using the last example with `ssh_command` option is the only command that works when connecting to FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

**apt instal sshfs sshpass**

**nano /etc/fstab**

> sshfs#remoteuser@remotehost:/remoteshare /mnt/remoteshare   fuse
> _netdev,port=65022,idmap=user,allow_other,ssh_command=sshpass\040-f\040/root/.ssh/host.password\040ssh,reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=60  0  0

**nano /root/.ssh/host.password**

> MyRemoteUserPasswordInClear

**mount -a**

Important part is \040 in mount option